# how do i restrict wordpress from displaying a specific post on the post page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i have a post with the following ids
$posts_id=array(1,2,3,4,5);
i don't feel like displaying every post on the post page. i want to exclude some post ids from the post page. Taking for example  i want to remove post id with 2 and 3 from getting displayed.
how do i achieve this in wordpress. this is all i have.

```
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile?>
        <?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Add more clarification to your question. On what page template are you when you are executing this query? My suggestion is to look in [pre_get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: am executing this on an index.php file using word press default template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pre_get_posts()` action. add this code in your themes `function.php` file

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    if( is_home() ) {
//add condition in which page you don't want to display post.
//WordPress by default home page is post page 
      $query->set('post__not_in', array(2,3));
//add post id which you want to remove from listing ex: array(2,3)
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post' );
```

> Edit
>   Remove from other page

Used `is_page` (Page ID, title, slug of page ) to remove the post from particular page

```
function exclude_post($query) {
        if( is_home()  || is_page (Page ID, title, slug of page )) {
    //add condition in which page you don't want to display post.
    //WordPress by default home page is post page 
          $query->set('post__not_in', array(2,3));
    //add post id which you want to remove from listing ex: array(2,3)
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post' );
```

Comment: thank you guys. it worked , but with this i should be able to call the post id i removed on another page that is not been seen by wordpress as a post page.

Comment: thanks, i just got what you mean @ Ankur Bhadania, it really help

Answer (score 1):

Use [pre_get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action like this:

```
function exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', array(2,3));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts_home');
```

And put this in your `functions.php` file.

This should affect your home page (if you've set your home to be posts page without having `home.php` the default page template should fall back to `index.php`).

Also check [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).